# Correct Orientation from Blender to Unreal Engine 5 in a spline

Tags: textures, blender, materials, fbx, unreal-5

Let me preface this by saying I'm an absolute beginner and I have no idea what I'm doing.

Following lot's of different tutorials, I want to create a road spline in unreal engine. Therefor I created a simple road model in blender and exported it as an fbx:

I made a very simple road model in blender and exported it as an fbx:

[image]

I then hooked up the following blueprint in UE5

[image]

where Road is a SplineComponent.

The `Add Spline Mesh Component` function has the following settings

[image]

But when I drag the spline blueprint into the scene it looks like this (it's distorted and rotated)

[image]

What went wrong and how do I fix it?